# SlickGrid DataView filter function behaving abnormally

Tags: javascript, filtering, slickgrid

In my custom filter function that I set by calling `setFilter()` on my `DataView`, I did the following to troubleshoot a problem with my filtering algorithm:

```
function myFilter(item) {
    console.dir(item);
    console.dir(arguments);
}
```

To my surprise, I got the following output (pseudo-output):

- **Object** - the actual item object
- **Arguments** - a two-item array where the first item is the data set array (that DataView uses) and the second argument is undefined.

How can this (i.e. `arguments[0] !== item`) be?

Comment: Asking & answering own question as documentation to potentially help other users who might suffer a similar symptom. Googling didn't yield any results for me. Hopefully now it will for others...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After spending hours scratching my head and contemplating on what I thought I knew about how functions work (while blaming my lack of sleep), I finally thought about checking SlickGrid code. I found out the hard way that SlickGrid recompiles the filtering function (using toString() and string massaging) for caching/optimization and therefore the actual `arguments` array doesn't match the original method signature.

As another side effect, you cannot use non-global variables that are bound to the closure of the filtering function.

The proper way to bind variables to the closure of the filtering function is to use the `setFilterArgs()` method of DataView. The `undefined` I saw as the second item of the `arguments` array in my (recompiled) filtering function was actually a slot for receiving what's passed through `setFilterArgs()`.

**Update**

Here's what SlickGrid does to the filter function. Test function:

```
function (item) {
    // my code here
}
```

Recompiled version (reformatted for readability):

```
function (_items, _args) {
    var _retval = [], _idx = 0;
    var item, undefined = _args;

    for (var _i = 0, _il = _items.length; _i < _il; _i++) {
        item = _items[_i];

        // my code here
    }

    return _retval;
}
```

Comment: I figured this out the hard way too. Although https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example-optimizing-dataview.html pointed me to the right direction

Answer (score 6):

FYI:  I've made the filter function inlining optional and configurable via "inlineFilters".  The setting is off by default.

Comment: Super! And thanks for SlickGrid. It's one awesome piece of software.